# How to combine a list of dictionaries to one dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dicts:

```
d =[{'a': 4}, {'b': 20}, {'c': 5}, {'d': 3}]
```

I want to remove the curly braces and convert `d` to a single dict which looks like:

```
d ={'a': 4, 'b': 20, 'c': 5, 'd': 3}
```

Comment: Your output is not a list, it is a dictionary.

Comment: You know dictionaries don't contain duplicates, right? So what would you do with elements with the same "key" in the list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't mind duplicate keys replacing earlier keys you can use:

```
from functools import reduce  # Python 3 compatibility 
d = reduce(lambda a, b: dict(a, **b), d)
```

This merges the first two dictionaries then merges each following dictionary into the result built so far.

Demo:

```
>>> d =[{'a': 4}, {'b': 20}, {'c': 5}, {'d': 3}]
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: dict(a, **b), d)
{'a': 4, 'c': 5, 'b': 20, 'd': 3}
```

Or if you need this to work for arbitrary (non string) keys (and you are using Python 3.5 or greater):

```
>>> d =[{4: 4}, {20: 20}, {5: 5}, {3: 3}]
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: dict(a, **b), d) # This wont work
TypeError: keywords must be strings
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: {**a, **b}, d) # Use this instead
{4: 4, 20: 20, 5: 5, 3: 3}
```

The first solution hacks the behaviour of keyword arguments to the dict function. The second solution is using the more general ** operator introduced in [Python 3.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

Comment: In my opinion this is a little bit complicated :D Or is something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 5):

You just need to iterate over `d` and append (`update()`) the element to a new dict e.g. `newD`.

```
d =[{'a': 4}, {'b': 20}, {'c': 5}, {'d': 3}]

newD = {}
for entry in d:
    newD.update(entry)

>>> newD
{'c': 5, 'b': 20, 'a': 4, 'd': 3}
```

Note: If there are duplicate values in `d` the last one will be appear in `newD`.

Comment: In case order is important, we can use OrderedDict as well !

Comment: @NihalSharma: Thanks for pointing this out! :) Of course we can if we want :D

Answer (score 1):

Overwriting the values of existing keys, a brutal and inexperienced solution is

```
nd = {}
for el in d:
    for k,v in el.items():
    nd[k] = v
```

or, written as a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {k:v for el in d for k,v in el.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [{'a': 4}, {'b': 20}, {'c': 5}, {'d': 3}]
b = {}
[b.update(c) for c in a]

b = {'a': 4, 'b': 20, 'c': 5, 'd': 3}
```

if order is important:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
a = [{'a': 4}, {'b': 20}, {'c': 5}, {'d': 3}]
newD = OrderedDict()
[newD.update(c) for c in a]
out = dict(newD)
```

Comment: I thought it was not required!! :/